# Laurent series for $\frac{z}{1+z^3}$ for $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I managed a decent start but got stuck:

$|z|>1$ implies $1/|z|<1$, so we can use $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{-k} = \frac{1}{1-1/z}$ to help find the Laurent series:

$$\frac{z}{1+z^3} =\frac{z-1}{1+z^3}\frac{1}{1-1/z} = \frac{z-1}{(z-1)(z^2-z-1)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{-k} = \frac{1}{z^2-z-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{-k}  $$

But now I have this nasty factor out in front, when I'm looking for an answer which is only powers of $z$. I thought about factorising the quadratic but it wouldn't help get an answer only in terms of powers of $z.$ Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about $\frac{z}{1+z^3}=\frac{1/z^2}{1+1/z^3}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k z^{-3k-2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac z {1+z^{3}}=\frac  1{z^{2}} \frac  1{1+z^{-3}}=\frac  1{z^{2}}  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}z^{-3n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $w = 1/z$. Then
$$
\frac{z}{1 + z^3} = \frac{zw^3}{w^3 + z^3 w^3} = \frac{w^2}{1 + w^3}.
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{w^2}{1 + w^3} = \frac{w^2}{1 - (-w^3)}
= w^2 \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {(-w^3)^k}
= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {(-1)^k w^{3k+2}}
$$
for $0 < |w| < 1$.
Hence
$$
\frac{z}{1 + z^3} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^k}{z^{3k + 2}}}
$$
for $|z| > 1$.